# Why does Xcode simulator launch app with didEnterRegion call, while iPhone does not?

Tags: xcode, debugging, logging

I'm troubleshooting a location-based app launch cycle that works fine on iOS simulator, but apparently does not launch the app on an actual device.

I've set up UNNotifications for both enter and exit events. Both the simulator and the device(s) register and display these notifications.

The next thing that is supposed to happen is that the app goes through a launch process, setting the app's state in such a way that I can tell without being connected to the debugger whether the app has launched or not when I open it from the home screen.

On simulator, the didEnterRegion code gets called and I can step through the subsequent launch code using the debugger - success.

However when I take the device out (for a walk) all I get are UNNotifications, and no app launch (which I can tell from the UI in the app on the real device)

I'm sure I need to improve my testing strategy (welcome to suggestions!), but at this point I should be able to expect that the app should behave the same on the simulator and the actual device - it is not.

Why is the expected outcome happening on the simulator but not on the device?

LocationService.swift

```
func handleRegionEnterEvent (for region: CLRegion) {
    ApplicationController.sharedInstance.didEnterRegion(region)
}

func handleRegionExitEvent (for region: CLRegion) {
    ApplicationController.sharedInstance.didExitRegion(region)
}
```

ApplicationController.swift

```
func didEnterRegion (_ region: CLRegion) {
    // Present Alert
    delegate?.handleUNEvent(note: "ENTER: \(region.identifier)")

    // Start launch cycle

}
```

AppDelegate.swift

```
extension AppDelegate: AppControllerDelegate {
    func handleUNEvent(note: String?) {
        // Show an alert if application is active
        if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
            guard let message = note else { return }
            Alert().showAlert(withMessage: "Application received UN while active: \(message)", title: "UNNotification")
        } else {
            // Otherwise present a local notification
            guard let body = note else { return }
            let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            notificationContent.body = body
            notificationContent.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
            notificationContent.badge = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1 as NSNumber
            let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "location_change",
                content: notificationContent,
                trigger: trigger)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are getting notifications then your app is running. You won't get a call to `didFinishLaunching` if your app is already running

Comment: @Paulw11 But isn't it true that "User-facing notifications communicate important information to users of your app, regardless of whether your app is running on the user's device" - Apple

Comment: Also, the app is definitely not running on simulator because the debug process has not yet attached (Launch manually option selected in "Edit Sheme..."

Comment: Do you post the notification by executing code in your `didEnterRegion`/`didExitRegion` functions?  How would these notifications be posted if your code wasn't running? Or have you created the notifications with a region trigger? It is always better to show your code in the question than describe what you have done to remove ambiguity.  Have you requested and received "always" location permission?

Comment: Edited question and included code. "Always" authorization...

Comment: Is it possible, that in ApplicationController.swift, `delegate?.handleUNEvent(note: "ENTER: \(region.identifier)")` gets called, but not the code after it?

Comment: You haven't shown any code after it. Is there code after "start the launch cycle"?

Comment: Sorry, removed for brevity. There is code and it works just fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189554/discussion-between-paulw11-and-elight).

Answer (score 0):

The simulator sadly has a lot of differences from a device both in terms of data reported (you will not get speed for example) and also as you saw call flow may be different...

Something to check is to make sure you have the descriptions for the specific location permissions you are asking for in relation to location set up.  For entering regions you probably want to make sure you have "always" access.

It may also be worth enabling wireless debugging, and walking around with laptop tethered to the device to verify with the debugger the didEnterRegion is truly not called, and there is a bug in the code that is supposed to display the UI you are expecting.  At the very least perhaps you could get better logging as to the status of various location callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

What happened: Code that executed on simulator was indeed crashing on the device and I was not reviewing crash logs from the device. This question arose from an issue that is neither ios, or core-location specific.

It has everything to do with choosing appropriate testing strategies and using all available information at one's disposal before coming to what may turn out to be premature conclusions.

> However when I take the device out (for a walk) all I get are UNNotifications, and no app launch (which I can tell from the UI in the app on the real device)

I was mistaken to think that a) User Notifications that appear when the App is not running are presented by the system (as banners) and b) the App launches in another process. In fact my own code specifically executes the code that makes those notifications appear. Face-to-palm: Copying code from tutorials to achieve quick test results without even trying to understand what the code does can lead to that I suppose.

In Xcode, plug in your device and hit command-shift-2 to open Devices & Simulators window. Select your device on the left and hit "View Logs" button to bring up your crash log.